# Simplifying File Upload from Telegram to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, telegram-bot, pre-signed-url, telegram-api

I have a web application integrated with Telegram. When a user uploads a file to Telegram, these files needs to be saved in storage like S3.
I can achieve this by following these steps:

1. GET api - get a presigned URL from S3.
2. Download the file in-memory using the Telegram download method.
3. Upload the downloaded file to S3 using the obtained presigned URL.

Resources online only explain how to upload a file by storing locally on the server
I'm wondering if there is any way to directly upload files from Telegram to S3 using a presigned URL? Alternatively, is it possible to optimize the download and upload process so that the file is streamed from Telegram to S3 without being stored locally?

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve a more streamlined file upload process from Telegram to AWS S3 would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!